# How to subset dataframe based on presence of words in string?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, subset, series

I'm attempting to subset a data frame based on the presence of one or more words in a diagnosis description field.

For example, running the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
member_id = ['A0001','A0001','A0001','B0002','B0002','C0003','C0003','C0003','C0003']
icd_desc = ['Knee pain','Obesity','Osteoarthritis right knee','Lung cancer','Bipolar disorder','','Cardiovascular','Epidermal','Severe trauma']
df['member_id'] = member_id
df['icd_desc'] = icd_desc

df_kneeobesity = df[('Obesity' in df.icd_desc.split()) | ('Knee' in df.icd_desc.split()) | ('knee' in df.icd_desc.split())] 
df_kneeobesity
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I've determined the problem seems to be the `icd_desc` column is a pandas.core.series.Series data type instead of a string, but I've been unable to convert `icd_desc` to a string. My first thought was to run `df['icd_desc']= df['icd_desc'].astype(str)` but that hasn't worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `df_kneeobesity = df[df.icd_desc.str.contains(r'\b(?:obesity|knee)\b', case=False)].copy()` what you want?

Comment: For string operations on series (or df columns) you have to explicitly call it as a string operation, like `column.str.split()`

Comment: @coldspeed Yes, that worked, thank you!

Comment: @G.Anderson So in my above code, where would I insert `column.str.split()`?

Comment: @RobertF in place of `.split()`, use `.str.split()`

Comment: @G.Anderson I'm still seeing an error message: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'` when I substitute - I'll fiddle around some more. Will be nice to know two different solutions to this problem!

Comment: Rather than splitting the string and using 'in', which can be...weird...(If you want to see what is happening in `.str.split()`, you can just run `df['icd_desc_list']=df['icd_desc'].str.split()` and then view the `df`) you can use `.str.contains()` as in the comment by @coldspeed, but using your original masking syntax rather than regex:  `df_kneeobesity = df[(df.icd_desc.str.contains('Obesity')) | (df.icd_desc.str.contains('knee')) | (df.icd_desc.str.contains('knee'))]`

Comment: @G.Anderson Excellent, thank you.